# How to wrap tables with div element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to 'scan' the html and wrap any table in the HTML with a div?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it definitely is.

Comment: yes.. it is... look at [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use wrap

```
$('table').wrap('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes...

```
$(function() {
    $("table").wrap("<div />");
});
```

See here for more info on `.wrap()`...

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/